# How would you use GET which is an integer in an PDO execute?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm slowly trying to understand and switch from MySQL to PDO / MySQLi and now I want to try how I would do with PDO.

I would like to ask how you would use `$_GET`, which usually sets the User ID (number), in an `execute`. As far as I understand `execute` it only accept strings, so I tried it with `PDO::PARAM_INT`

```
$q = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `content` FROM `inventory` WHERE `id` = ?'); 

$q->execute(array($_GET['u_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT));
```

Unfortunately it didn't fix it. Is it missing a parameter? It returns me following:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in X on line Y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `PDO::PARAM_INT` when using `$q->bindParam()`, which you aren't doing:

```
$q->bindParam(1, $_GET['u_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->execute();
```

Here, you can just get rid of it:

```
$q->execute(array($_GET['u_id']));
```

[**PDO execute definitely works with non-string parameters; see the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: The type specifier is only applicable to bindParam. It has no meaning outside of the array list; it will just be ignored.